# Fetching url segment and changing the pagination link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My link is www.xxx.com/key/load

I want to check if the url contains "load" keword, then change the pagination url

from

```
<a href="www.xxx.com/key?p=xx">2</a>
```

to

```
<a href="www.xxx.com/key/load?p=xx">2</a>
```

Please help me to solve it, using jQuery.

Comment: I don't understand (and looks like I'm not alone) if the link is current url in addressbar or link in anchor

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if(this.href && this.href.indexOf('/load') ===-1) {
       s=this.href;
       a=s.split('?');
       this.href=a[0]+'/load?'+a[1];
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/F6r42/1/)

Comment: The keyword "load" gets added to the anchor link even though if the browser url does not have "load" in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("load") > -1) {
            alert("your url contains the name load");
           }
     });
</script>
```

Something like this should check if your url containes the string/word load.

hope it helps